# PHP json decode from database

Tags: php, codeigniter, json

I have this `json encode` in the database, and i want just echo values `name_r` in `foreach` , how is it?

```
[{
    "name_r": "saeed",
    "units": ["salam", "11", "11", "khobe", "22", "22", "salam"],
    "price_change": ["33", "33", "33", "44", "44", "44"]
}, {
    "name_r": "salavat",
    "units": ["55", "55", "khobe", "66", "66"],
    "price_change": ["77", "77", "77", "88", "88", "88", "99", "99", "99"]
}]
```

this my php, that have error(`Message: Undefined index: name_r - Line Number: 179`):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id desc");
    $data = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $data[] = json_decode($row->residence,true);
        echo $data["name_r"].'<br>'; //Line Number: 179
    }
```

Comment: Does the *residence* column contain the posted JSON data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `json_encoded` data you provided is stored in one row of the database, the `json_decode` will give you an array of arrays. To echo all the `name_r` fields, you would need to:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    $data = json_decode($row->residence,true);
    foreach($data as $datum){
        echo $datum['name_r'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You used `[]` in your assignment. This means that the result of the `json_decode` will be pushed at the end of your array.

Using `var_dump($data)` should help you understand what your array actually looks like, and solve your problem by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the example JSON you showed is data from a single record. The data is an array of objects, so you'll need an inner loops that loops over the array from each returned record.

```
foreach ($row->residence as &$value) {
    $data = json_decode($value,true);
    echo $data["name_r"].'<br>';
}
```

I am not a PHP dev, so I am unsure if my syntax is right. But hopefully you get the idea.