# Message: Illegal string offset (decode JSON with codeigniter and mysql)

Tags: mysql, json, decode, codeigniter-3

I have a table (tb_proxmox) with 2 field (proxmox_id, proxmox_data). My record in field **proxmox_data** (this dummy record)

```
{"ip0_proxmox":"31231","ip1_proxmox":"31312313","ip2_proxmox":"","nama_proxmox":"31","port_proxmox":"3131","user_proxmox":"","pwd_proxmox":"","type_proxmox":"","ram_proxmox":"","storage_proxmox":""}
```

My function in my controller

```
    $data = array(
        'ambil_data' => $this->M_proxmox->tampilData('tb_proxmox'), 
        );
```

My function in my model (M_proxmox)

```
    public function tampilData($table){
    return $this->db->get($table)->result();
  }
```

In my View

```
              <tbody>
              <?php
                $no = 1;
                foreach ($ambil_data as $row) {
                $datas = json_decode($row->proxmox_data,true);
                foreach($datas as $datum){
              ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $no++ ;?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row->proxmox_id; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $datum['ip1_proxmox'];?></td>

                  <td><a href="#" class="fa fa-pencil"></a><a href="#" class="fa fa-remove"></a></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
              <?php
                  }
                }
                ?>
```

I got this error
 **Illegal string offset 'ip1_proxmox'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got this error, because you are iterating through decoded json and `$datum` variable contains only values, not keys.

If you want to get data from json this way, you have to change your view:

```
<tbody>
<?php
    $no = 1;
    foreach ($ambil_data as $row) {
        $datas = json_decode($row->proxmox_data,true);
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no++ ;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->proxmox_id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $datas['ip1_proxmox'];?></td>

        <td><a href="#" class="fa fa-pencil"></a><a href="#" class="fa fa-remove"></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</tbody>
```

I also moved `</tbody>` outside foreach.

Comment: you're right! thank you. I've seen from [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462250/php-json-decode-from-database) that use 2 foreach